# How to get, in java, the entire html of a page loaded in part from jquery

Tags: java, web-scraping, rhino

i need to develope a web application that allows me to scrape a page that is load partially using jquery. i learn that in php this is not possible [writing this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507523/how-to-get-in-php-the-entire-html-of-a-page-loaded-in-part-from-jquery)

I read about [rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/), but i don't know how to use that for my scope,
does someone know how to do that in java? is possible to have some example? thanks!!!!

Comment: It *is* possible in PHP; but, like [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example) mentioned below, you must use a browser interface that is not written in PHP. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10517783/564406) to your first question.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a browser interface.

The most commonly used browser interface (or driver) is selenium: http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example

You can use selenium to open a browser of your choice to open the website. It has javascript support, so you'll be able to traverse the DOM via XPath or CSS selectors.